# Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xe4' in file main.py on line 46, but no encoding declared

Tags: python, linux, discord.py

I am trying to run my main.py on a linux server and I get the following traceback: "Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xe4' in file main.py on line 46, but no encoding declared". Same code works on windows fine without any tracebacks. Line 46 is "@client.command()". What can I do?

Comment: What encoding does your Windows box use?

Answer (score 1):

You might have `\xe4` in a comment area, try to put following line at the top of your python file :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: When I do this, i get the following traceback:

SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 21: invalid        continuation byte

Comment: Then it's not in comments, can you paste the line ?

Comment: SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 21: invalid continuation byte

Comment: i paste # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

Comment: the * doesnt load i dont know why. But i paste on first line the code you sent me

Comment: Sorry I meant the line (46, the complete line) in your python file which contains the error. The line must contain 0xe4 character.